# vbscript MS-Word Listformat Listtemplates

Tags: vbscript, ms-word, dialog

I have a small question about vbscript and microsoft word. I want to number my titel like

> 4.1.Titel

with vbscript. Normally I do it like this:

```
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = oWord.Documents.Add()
oWord.Selection.Style = "Überschrift 2"
oWord.Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyNumberDefault
oWord.Selection.TypeText("Titel"+ vbCr)
```

and I become:

> 4.Titel

So I changed it to

```
oWord.Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate //OR
oWord.Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate(1)
```

but I get an error:

> wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

What do I do wrong?

Comment: that the arguments are wrong

Comment: Look, if you want help, you're going to have to be more specific.  We cannot read minds.  Provide the text of the error message.

Comment: `wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment`. I tried with **oWord.Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate(1)** but it is wrong

Comment: And what line is throwing that error?  Also, please update your question, don't put substantive information in the comments.

Comment: If you look up the documentation for ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate you will see that the first parameter needs to be a ListTemplate object, not an index to a ListTemplate object. So that is the first thing you need to correct. Beyond that I am not sure applying a ListTemplate is the right way to go...